# Sublime Text 2 HTML5 Syntax Not Underlining Matching Tags

Tags: settings, sublimetext2, syntax-highlighting

I'm not aware of changing any settings that would have caused this, but for some reason, when the language type is set as `HTML5`, Sublime has stopped displaying an underline beneath matching tags.  I've grown accustomed to this feature in any editor I use, and I've come to rely on it to catch unclosed tags.

When the language type is set to `HTML`, the underlining behaves normally.  Only when `HTML5` is the language is there a problem.

As `HTML5` is the default language type (by choice) for several languages that I program in, this is quite inconvenient.

Does anyone know where I can look to alter this?

It doesn't appear to be theme related, as it behaves similarly across themes, and the `HTML` underlining will work with the same theme that it isn't working in `HTML5`.

Comment: The underlining is being done by some plugin. I know [BracketHighlighter](https://github.com/facelessuser/BracketHighlighter) is popular for that feature, though you may be using something else. You may want to try creating an issue for the plugin you are using. The developer would probably have better insight. Of course, if you can find what plugin it is, it's probably worthwhile to add that to your question.

Comment: I have `BracketHighlighter` disabled, and the `HTML` underlining still works.  Are you saying that aspect of syntax highlighting is not a native feature, and only shows up because of some plugin?  I can't remember how it looked before any installed plugins.

Comment: Oh sorry I guess you mean the dotted lines. It may be that HTML5 is not recognized in the same way as HTML. That's just a guess though.