# Syntax in Sublime Text 2 Converts From "HTML" to "HTML (RAILS)" on save

Tags: html, sublimetext2, syntax-highlighting

I've tried various fixes with this, and it is really annoying me now.

Whenever I open a file as html, the default syntax for the file changes to `HTML (RAILS)`.  I can flip it back to HTML by the little select list in the corner, but it reverts.  I've tried changing syntax specific files, setting extensions, etc.  I even grepped `HTML (RAILS)` in my Sublime root folder recursively, and found nothing.

The thing that makes it hard to pin down, is that there is no extension difference.  No matter  which syntax highlighting I choose, the tag is the same.

I don't need syntax highlighting or autocomplete for HTML, but I do really like how matching tags are underlined in HTML syntax highlighting, and without it, I often miss unmatched tags, and cause lots of extra work for myself.

Any guesses on what this is / how to restore HTML to proper clean HTML highlighting?

(Note: The behaviour is identical for HTML and HTML5 and as I discussed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18138880/sublime-text-2-html5-syntax-not-underlining-matching-tags), I can't get tag matching to work in `HTML5` anyway.  That problem preceeded this one, but using HTML instead of HTML5 was an acceptable fix - that no longer works.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else has this bizarre issue, I've solved it.

There is a package installed (dont' remember if it was installed from the beginning, or if I added it) called Syntax Matcher.  I commented out the following lines in a file called `SyntaxHighlighter.py`:

```
    if self.ext == '.html':
         self.set_syntax('HTML (Rails)', 'Rails')
          return True
```

And the problem was solved instantly.